# Meteor login via Third party library

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm trying to login to my meteor site via a third party library like this one:
https://gist.github.com/gabrielhpugliese/4188927

In my server.js i have:

```
Meteor.methods({
facebook_login: function (fbUser, accessToken) {
    var options, serviceData, userId;
    serviceData = {
        id: fbUser.id,
        accessToken: accessToken,
        email: fbUser.email
    };
    options = {
        profile: {
            name: fbUser.name
        }
    };
    userId = Accounts.updateOrCreateUserFromExternalService('facebook', serviceData, options);
    return userId;
}, ......
```

In my client.js I have:

```
    facebookLogin: function () {
    if (Meteor.user())
        return;
    if (!Session.equals("deviceready", true))
        return;
    if (!Session.equals("meteorLoggingIn", false))
        return;

    // Do not run if plugin not available
    if (typeof window.plugins === 'undefined')
        return;
    if (typeof window.plugins.facebookConnect === 'undefined')
        return;
    // After device ready, create a local alias
    var facebookConnect = window.plugins.facebookConnect;
    console.log('Begin activity');
    Session.equals("meteorLoggingIn", true);
    Accounts._setLoggingIn(true);
    facebookConnect.login({
        permissions: ["email", "user_about_me"],
        appId: "123456789012345"
    }, function (result) {
        console.log("FacebookConnect.login:" + JSON.stringify(result));

        // Check for cancellation/error
        if (result.cancelled || result.error) {
            console.log("FacebookConnect.login:failedWithError:" + result.message);
            Accounts._setLoggingIn(false);
            Session.equals("meteorLoggingIn", false);
            return;
        }

        var access_token = result.accessToken;

        Meteor.call('facebook_login', result, access_token, function (error, user) {
            Accounts._setLoggingIn(false);
            Session.equals("meteorLoggingIn", false);
            if (!error) {
                var id = Accounts._makeClientLoggedIn(user.id, user.token);
                console.log("FacebookConnect.login: Account activated " + JSON.stringify(Meteor.user()));
            } else {
                // Accounts._makeClientLoggedOut();
            }
        }); 
    });
}, // login
facebookLogout: function () {
    Meteor.logout();
    // var facebookConnect = window.plugins.facebookConnect;
    // facebookConnect.logout();
},
```

The third party library (Facebook Android SDK in my case) works fine. My problem is after the "var id = Accounts._makeClientLoggedIn(user.id, user.token);" the Meteor.user() returns Undefined. However If I do a page refresh in the browser works fine and the template renders as a logged in user.

Anyone knows how to fix the 'Undefined' on client ??

PS. On server side the users collection looks fine. The meteor token and everything else are there.

Answer (score 1):

Solved. I had to add : this.setUserId(userId.id);
after userId = Accounts.updateOrCreateUserFromExternalService('facebook', serviceData, options); at server.js

Answer (score 0):

Meteor's client side javascript can't run fibers. Fibers allows synchronous code to be used with javascript since by design js is asynchronous. This means there are callbacks that need to be used to let you know when the task is complete.

From what it looks like `Accounts._makeClientLoggedIn` doesn't take a callback & unfortunately and doesn't return any data looking at its source. I can't say i've tried this myself because I can't test your code without the android sdk but have you tried using [Deps.flush](http://docs.meteor.com/#deps_flush) to do a reactive flush?

Also Meteor also has very clean and easy facbeook integration. If you simply add the facebook meteor package

```
meteor add accounts-facebook
```

You can get access to a lovely `Meteor.loginWithFacebook` method that can make everything reactive and your code simpler and really easy. If you need to modify it to use the Android SDK Dialog instead you can easily modify the code out as the code for the module is [out there for you to hack up to your spec](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/master/packages/accounts-facebook)

**Edit: If you're using an external SDK such as the java SDK/cordova plugin**

Set your plugin so that it redirects to the following URL (set up for meteor.com hosting):

```
http://yourmeteorapp.meteor.com/_oauth/facebook?display=touch&scope=your_scope_request_params&state=state&code=yourOAuthCodeFromJava&redirect=YourAPP
```

So in the querystring we have:

- scope= Contains your facebook scope params (for permissions)
- code= Your OAuth code from the java sdk
- redirect=Where to redirect to after once logged in instead of the window.close
- state= A cros site forgery state value, any random value will do

This url is basically used to mimic would what be given to the REDIRECT_URI at : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/

This will redirect to meteor's OAuth helper (at https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/accounts-oauth-helper/oauth_server.js)

So what would happen is you give the OAuth code from Java to meteor, it fetches the OAuth token and the user's data, then redirect the user to a URL in your app

Comment: Akshat thanks for answering. However in this particular project I use an Apache Cordova app to view my meteor site. That way I have access to device features (e.g. Accelerometer, Camera, etc) from my meteor site. Currently I cannot use accounts-facebook (doesn't work) because of the problem I describe here: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/872

Comment: I also use cordova for something similar albeit not the same entirely, why not alter the new window to a `window.location.href =` and use `display=touch` in the dialog auth url so it works well on mobiles? I did this particularly to reduce complexity with the fb-js-sdk which has been very glitchy as of late on android devices

Comment: I understand why you want to avoid fb-js-sdk but I don't use that. I use the java Android SDK (packed within cordova app) and I only load the javascript interface from within meteor. This way I call a native action for login and get the results back to javascript (extremely stable). I'm not sure about your window.location.href instead of a popup idea, because I believe the oath_server will respond by sending a '<html><head><script>window.close()</script></head></html>' back to the client and the application will exit.

Comment: I see thats a bit more clear, actually you can avoid the `window.close` if you use display=touch` or use `redirect=` instead of  close in the redirect_uri. I've slightly changed the answer so you can use the OAuth code returned from the plugin's login dialog to meteor by going straight to the redirect_uri when logging in. You would also have to give this same redirect_uri to your java plugin so that the token is valid.

Comment: Glad you did. For many reasons (including some security ones) the accounts-facebook and the lovely Meteor.loginWithFacebook method is the right way to go. Once I can make it work from inside cordova i will revert my code back to that. The plugin i'm using now for cross platform compatibility is the official facebook-connect plugin for cordova https://github.com/mgcrea/cordova-facebook-connect Unfortunately it does have only a .login and .logout methods and no way for me to set the url so i can test your answer.